# Windows program to monitor a log file for new lines and automatically display them as they are added to the file

Tags: windows, text-editor

I have text file, like `log.txt` which constantly updates.
I want some text editor which I can open on separate monitor to display this file.
I want this text editor to "reload" text file from disk periodically (every N seconds) and to scroll down.
What can you recommend?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you prefer a GUI, you can use [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/):

- free and paid versions available
- Windows
- Portable
- Like "tail -f" on Unix systems, but with many more features

[image]

- Tail multiple files

[image]

- Configurable highlighting

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Optimised real-time viewing engine
- View files of any size (> 2GB)
- Scroll to any point in the whole file instantly
- View files over a network
- Configurable line wrapping
- Configurable TAB expansion
- Configurable font, including spacing and offset to maximise use of screen space

Comment: i like this tool, very handy

Comment: i tried all suggestions but this tool is the best, it's very fast and works fine even when log file grows fast

Comment: Franck, I'm sorry at offtop. What effect do you use on your first two screenshots? Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных I got the screenshots from the web

Comment: @СашаЧерных FastStone Capture (http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) can do the blurring effects on screenshots.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to watch the log as it grows, look at the 'tail' utility in a command line window.

There's a port of some of the most common unix utilities to Windows at http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/
That package has the advantage that it requires nothing in the way of support - just drop the files somewhere in your path and they just work.

To use tail to watch a log file, open up a command line window (cmd.exe) and do:

```
tail -f <log.txt>
```

It'll just keep scrolling out the contents as the log file grows. Ctrl-C to stop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) 
(free, included in Windows XP and later):

```
Get-Content test.txt -Wait
```

[image]

To change width:

[image]

[image]

---

Useful info left by [ADTC](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/7401/adtc) as a comment: you should also change the Defaults if you want the width to be saved and restored on a new PowerShell instance, see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: i like it because it doesn't require additional software. default window width is 80, can I add some argument to change window width to 120 or 150?

Comment: @javapowered sure, added to answer.

Comment: You may want to mention that you should also change the **Defaults** if you want the width to be saved and restored on a new PowerShell instance. You can use [this screenshot link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HvjRW.png).

Answer (score 3):

If you have Git (or *GitHub*) installed, you can find the `tail` utility available in *Git Shell**. You can use it to follow any file:

```
tail -f logfile.log
```

Those experienced with Unix and Linux terminals will find this very familiar. Try `tail --help` for more information.

<sup>* Usually this is a modified instance of *Windows PowerShell*.</sup>

You can also find the `less` utility installed with Git. As per the help text:

```
                         MOVING
F                    Forward forever; like "tail -f".
```

**Note:** I don't recommend installing Git just for this. But if you already have Git installed, there's no need to find third party `tail` or `less` utilities.

Answer (score 1):

[Log Expert](https://logexpert.codeplex.com/) is an open source alternative that is quite feature-rich. It has a so called *tail mod*e to view the end of the file.

Some standard features:

- colorization of rows based on regex patterns
- search

Some original features:

- columnizers - split a log row into fields and interpret fields as date, time, or various other  data types (you can write your own custom columnizer).
- time sync - you can sync two files, and jumping to a certain time in one of them will sync the other to the same (or close) time

[This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRC6Nb1VYT0) contains a screencast of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `less`, a free and open-source tool written and maintained by Mark Nudelman.

`less +F log.txt`

The advantage of `less` is that you can toggle it between being a file viewer (this disables automatic scrolling, and lets you search and scroll manually) and a log follower.  Ctrl+C takes you into "less" mode (file viewer mode).  And Shift+F returns you to follow mode.

Comment: The question is tagged Windows. I don't think ``less`` would work there

Comment: @Timmy:  There are ways to install `less` on Windows.  If the asker needs help doing so, he can post a comment here and ask for advice.

Answer (score 0):

During development I use Emacs text editor to monitor logs.

`emacs-w32` from Cygwin is easier way to get Emacs and necessary environment.

Tail update to certain kinds of files can be added via:

```
(defun my/auto-revert-tail-mode-hook ()
  "Enable `auto-revert-tail-mode' for file in 'log' dir or ending on '.log'"
  (when (string-match "/logs?/\\|\\.\\(?:log\\|out\\)\\'"
                      (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))
    (auto-revert-tail-mode 1)
    ))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my/auto-revert-tail-mode-hook)
```

With TRAMP and `ssh` installed I can see updates in remote log files!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote such a tool ("loxx") you can have a try at https://loxx.app/wp-content/uploads/loxx_setup.exe.
It supports filtering, color highlighting, regex search, time stamps and much more also for running logs (used Baretail for a long long time but missed some features).
[image]