# Log file monitor with notifications for Windows

Tags: windows, logs, notification

I'm looking for a Windows tool that monitors log files and shows notification when certain events appear. I already [did](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+viewer+%5Bwindows%5D) [various](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+notification+%5Bwindows%5D) [searches](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+monitor+%5Bwindows%5D) and the closest question was [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11218/windows-program-to-monitor-a-log-file-for-new-lines-and-automatically-display-th/11233#11233), which suggests BareTail.

I'm already familiar with BareTail; it's nice for looking at logs but it's limited: it can only highlight lines, doesn't support regular expressions or even wildcards, and it needs to be constantly in the foreground to be useful.

The ideal tool would just sit in the background, maybe with a system tray icon, and only show notifications when lines appear in the specified log file that match defined regexes.

For example, when monitoring the log file of chocolatey I want to be notified when the `choco upgrade all` command is started and finished and when package updates are found and finished installing.

But it should be flexible enough to be used with about any log file.

I would prefer open source, but I'm not averse to paid software.

Comment: Welcome Gerald!  Great question.  Upvoted.  Can you add to your question (and tags, if gratis) if you are looking for gratis or commercial software?  Thanks, and again, welcome!